# Upgrading Angular Typescript Access missing members

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, tslint

I'm upgrading an Angular project from an older version 4.0 to 7.0, I have the following piece of code

```
 foo = {};
 foo.bar = 23;
```

This will throw error `Property 'bar' does not exist on value type of '{}'`

I know how to fix this by either

```
foo: any = {};
```

or

```
foo['bar'] = 23;
```

The problem is that it appears in lots of places and I don't want to fix them manually line by line or using Find/Replace which might break the code base.

**Question:** Is there a way to use tslint or ng lint to fix the entire project for this type of error?

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is there a way to use tslint or ng lint to fix the entire project for this type of error

No. Neither of those tools (or any existing tool) offer that option.

## Advanced

You can lookup writing your own codemods, but its not for the faint of heart.